# date picker setting should be changed to pick date from net instead of system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I want datepicker to pick current date from a url and not from the system. Can any one suggest some way to do it? Cause i'm completely new in this.
HTML

```
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="datepicker" value="" class="text-input" size="50" />
```

script

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', minDate: tomorrow, maxDate: "1" }).attr('readonly','readonly');

    });
   </script>
```

Comment: Note sure what you're asking, the Date object in js based on the browsers OS system time, but the Date object also has access to UTC time.

Comment: I want to UTC time access from some url what i should @MattWilson

Comment: @Echo - your question makes no sense. At the moment, you're telling us that you'd like X so you can do Y. You can consider X = 'pick date from net instead of system' in this analogy. What are you actually trying to do? What is Y? There will be a better solution to Y that does not involve X.